# digitalocean kubernetes loadbalancer

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have deployed my app on the limited available Kubernetes cluster on DigitalOcean. 
I have a spring boot app with a service exposed on port 31744 for external using nodeport service config.

I created a Loadbalancer using the yaml config per DO link doc: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/kubernetes/how-to/add-load-balancer/

However, I am not able to hook up to my service. Can you advise on how it can be done so I can access my service from the loadbalancer?

The following is my "kubectl get svc" output for my app service:

```
NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)          AGE
my-springboot          NodePort       10.245.6.216    <none>           8080:31744/TCP   2d18h
kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.245.0.1      <none>           443/TCP          3d20h
sample-load-balancer   LoadBalancer   10.245.53.168   58.183.251.550   80:30495/TCP     2m6s
```

The following is my loadbalancer.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-load-balancer
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 31744
      name: http
```

My service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-springboot
  labels:
    app: my-springboot
    tier: backend
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: my-springboot
    tier: backend
```

Thanks

Comment: So what happens when you hit the External IP that is shown in Service command?

Comment: @Sonam, Can you share service configuration?

Comment: There is no content output on that external ip at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expose your service using `LoadBalancer` instead of `NodePort` you need to provide `type` in service as `LoadBalancer`. So your new service config yaml will be:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-springboot
  labels:
    app: my-springboot
    tier: backend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    # the port that this service should serve on
  - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: my-springboot
    tier: backend
```

Once you apply the above service yaml file, you will get the external IP in `kubectl get svc` which can be used to access the service from outside the kubernetes cluster.